# My own Android App causes my phone to crash

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-notifications

I am trying to learn how to trigger notifications on Android. The app works on the virtual device but when I try it on my actual Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android Version: 8.1.0), it freezes the phone everytime I press the notification button with a message that says "System UI has stopped" which makes my phone unresponsive indefinitely and requires restarting.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String CHANNEL1_ID = "Channel 1 id";
    String CHANNEL1_NAME = "Channel 1";
    String channel1_description = "Channel 1 description";
    String textTitle = "This is a title.";
    String textContent = "Some content.";
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final Context context = this;

        createNotificationChannel();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL1_ID);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_image);
                builder.setContentTitle(textTitle);
                builder.setContentText(textContent);
                builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notificationManager.notify(count, builder.build());

                count++;

                Log.d("TAG " + count, "onClick: ");

            }

        });

    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String name = CHANNEL1_NAME;
            String description = channel1_description;
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL1_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what does the crash logcat say ?

Comment: After clicking the button,

2020-03-15 07:05:33.112 19181-19181/com.example.createnotificationfromdocumentation D/TAG 1: onClick:

Comment: @Zain After crashing,
2020-03-15 07:05:37.333 19181-19181/com.example.createnotificationfromdocumentation D/ViewRootImpl@455257a[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add the following to my module level build.gradle
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:29.0.0"
since my target sdk version is 29.